# If $V$ is the internal direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$, then $W_1 \cap W_2 = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Just looking to double check this proof. I know that it's a bit longer than other proofs of the same theorem, but for me it's a little more natural.

To be clear, I'm not looking for alternative proofs. I'm specifically interested in whether or not my proof works. I'm also open to (specific & constructive) feedback as to whether specific parts of the proof could be made more concise or clear.

**Theorem**. Suppose $V$ is a vector space, and that $V$ is the internal direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$, namely, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$ with the property that any vector $v \in V$ can be uniquely decomposed as $v = w_1 + w_2$, with $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_2$. Then $W_1 \cap W_2 = 0$.

**Proof**. We proceed by contradiction. Suppose $V$ is the internal direct sum of subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$, and $W_1 \cap W_2 \neq 0$.

Because $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, both contain the additive identity, so by our hypothesis there exists another element of $W_1 \cap W_2$ not identical to zero, call it $w_\eta$.

Since $w_\eta \in W_1$ and $w_\eta \in W_2$ there are $w_1, w_1' \in W_1$ and $w_2, w_2' \in W_2$ such that:

$$ w_1 + w_1' = w_\eta \tag{1}$$
$$ w_2 + w_2' = w_\eta$$

Then

$$ w_1 - w_2' = -w_1' + w_2 = w_\eta - (w_2' + w_1') $$

Set

$$v_1 = w_1,$$
$$v_2 = w_2,$$
$$v_1' = -w_1',$$
$$v_2' = -w_2',$$
$$v_\eta = w_\eta - (w_2' + w_1')$$

whence we obtain the following two equalities:

$$v_1 + v_2' = v_\eta$$

$$v_1' + v_2 = v_\eta$$

If $v_i = v_i'$, we have $w_i = -w_i'$ for $i = 1, 2$, causing the left hand sides in $(1)$ to vanish. But we chose $w_\eta$ to be nonzero.

Otherwise, $v_i \neq v_i'$, and we have exhibited two distinct decompositions of the form $u_1 + u_2 = u_\eta$ for $u_1 \in W_1$, $u_2 \in W_2$, $u_\eta \in V$. But $V$ is the internal direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$, and each $u_\eta \in V$ should have had a single, unique decomposition.

In either case, our hypothesis that $W_1 \cap W_2 \neq 0$ is contradicted. Therefore it must be that $W_1 \cap W_2 = 0$. $\square$

Comment: I don't understand why you need $w_1'$ and $w_2'$ in equation (1) at all. Since $W_1$ is closed under addition, $w_1+w_1' \in W_1$, so why not just call the whole sum $w_1+w_1'$ by $w_1$? Why create two separate elements? And the same for $w_2+w_2'$...

Comment: Another way to say my previous comment is: the choices of $w_1$ and $w_1'$ are not unique. Why not just choose $w_1 = w_\eta$ and $w_1' = 0$? This would give the result much quicker.